# is this tomek link implementation faulty?

Tags: machine-learning

The algorithm definition for Tomek Links states: " Suppose {E1,…,En}⊂Rk is a dataset, with each Ei having exactly one of two labels + or −. A pair (Ei,Ej) is called a Tomek link if Ei and Ej have different labels, and there is not an El such that d(Ei,El)< d(Ei,Ej) or d(Ej,El)< d(Ei,Ej) ", where d(x,y) is the distance between x and y.

I created a "toy" data set so I could understand Tomek Links better (code attached). I used package "unbalanced" with its function ubTomek. The function implementation (it's on GitHub) is that it looks up the nearest neighbor of  the minority class points, and if they belong to the majority class - the couple is declared as a Tomek Link.
I think they are missing something, because they are only checking d(Ei,Ej) and they should also check d(Ej,Ei).
Any Opinions on this? If I am right - I'll drop the developers a message about a bug, if I'm wrong - I'll understand Tomek Links better.